# Get lines of multi-line string, Python

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to convert large string in lines, but failing if `\n` is occurred in it.

**Example string**

```
s1 = """
x = 10
y = 20
print(f"Sample Calculator:\n{x} + {y} = {x+y}")"""
```

```
lines = s1.splitlines() # Similar results on lines = s1.split('\n')
print(*lines, sep='\n------\n')
```

**output:**

```
------
x = 10
------
y = 20
------
print(f"Sample Calculator:
------
{x} + {y} = {x+y}")
```

**Required output:**

```
------
x = 10
------
y = 20
------
print(f"Sample Calculator:\n{x} + {y} = {x+y}")
```

Answer (score 2):

To preserve backslashes literally, you use a raw-string, denoted by the prefix `r`, so that you don't have to escape every occurrence of a backslash with another backslash:

```
s1 = r"""
x = 10
y = 20
print(f"Sample Calculator:\n{x} + {y} = {x+y}")"""
```

Comment: Yes! it works that way, but in my case I get it from user input, like s1 = input(), and I tried r`repr` and other `str.encode` but that do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to:

`print(f"Sample Calculator:\\n{x} + {y} = {x+y}")"""`

(I've escaped the backslash that will make it visible in the print instruction instead of treating it as a new line indicator)

[image: output]